# Unity App Crashes When Sign-In via Play Games is Attempted

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I have a problem that has been chasing me for the last few days.

I did all the necessary configuration to set up the Google Play Games sign-in method to my Unity game for Android.

However, every time I click the sign-in button the Play Games icon briefly appears at the top and the app suddenly crashes.

Analyzing the logcat, it seems there is an error **on the highlighted line** (last line of the 'InitializePlayGamesPlatform()' method) of the following script:

```css
using GooglePlayGames;
using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi;
using UnityEngine;

public class UserManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser firebaseUser;

    void Start()
    {
        InitializePlayGamesPlatform();
    }

    private void InitializePlayGamesPlatform()
    {
        PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder()
            .RequestServerAuthCode(false)
            .Build();

        PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);
        PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();

        ************firebaseAuth = Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;************
    }

    public void TrySignIn()
    {
        UnityEngine.Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) =>
        {
            if (!success)
            {
                Debug.LogError("UserManager: Failed to sign in into Play Games!");
                return;
            }

            string authCode = PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.GetServerAuthCode();

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(authCode))
            {
                Debug.LogError("UserManager: Failed to get auth code!");
                return;
            }

            Debug.LogFormat("UserManager: auth code is: {0}", authCode);

            Firebase.Auth.Credential credential = Firebase.Auth.PlayGamesAuthProvider.GetCredential(authCode);

            firebaseAuth.SignInWithCredentialAsync(credential).ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                if (task.IsCanceled)
                {
                    Debug.LogError("UserManager: sign-in was canceled!");
                    return;
                }

                if (task.IsFaulted)
                {
                    Debug.LogError("UserManager: error signing in!");
                    return;
                }

                firebaseUser = task.Result;
                Debug.LogFormat("UserManager: user signed in successfully: {0} ({1})", firebaseUser.DisplayName, firebaseUser.UserId);
            });
        });
    }

    public void TrySignOut()
    {
        firebaseAuth.SignOut();
    }
}
```

Also, there are some other messages/errors in the logcat, such as:

```
Failed to read Firebase options from the app's resources. Either make sure google-services.json is included in your build or specify options explicitly.

InitializationException:  Firebase app creation failed.

at Firebase.FirebaseApp.CreateAndTrack (Firebase.FirebaseApp+CreateDelegate createDelegate, Firebase.FirebaseApp existingProxy) [0x000da] in Z:\tmp\tmp.txs8ldQ514\firebase\app\client\unity\proxy

at Firebase.FirebaseApp.Create () [0x00000] in Z:\tmp\tmp.txs8ldQ514\firebase\app\client\unity\proxy\FirebaseApp.cs:119

at Firebase.FirebaseApp.get_DefaultInstance () [0x0000b] in Z:\tmp\tmp.txs8ldQ514\firebase\app\client\unity\proxy\FirebaseApp.cs:94

at Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.get_DefaultInstance () [0x00000] in Z:\tmp\tmp.poUq23PLco\firebase\auth\client\unity\proxy\FirebaseAuth.cs:294
```

I repeated every procedure from the beginning a thousand times, searched everywhere and got no results.

I have tried running an older version of GPG plugin as well, but no success at all.

I kindly ask you to help me on this - ***I promise to put your names on the credits in case I publish!!*** :)

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Firebase support member (@Jesus) has just helped me to figure the issue out. The workaround is directly adding the sourceset to the mainTemplate.gradle.

I had to do the following:

1. Go to **Project Settings** > **Publishing Settings** > **Build** > checkmark **Custom Main Gradle Template**.
   It will give you the location to the mainTemplate.gradle file.
   [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWSbw.png)  is an example.
2. Go to the given directory and open **mainTemplate.gradle** with a text editor.
3. Add the following code to the referred file, right after `lintOptions`:

`sourceSets { main { res.srcDirs += '<full path from your root directory to google-services.xml>' } }`

4. Also, add this array to noCompress under aaptOptions:

`noCompress = ['.unity3d', '.ress', '.resource', '.obb', 'google-services.json']`

In the end, the mainTemplate.gradle should look like this:

```
lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}

sourceSets { main { res.srcDirs += 'C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\Documents\\Unity Projects\\GAMENAME\\Assets\\Plugins\\Android\\Firebase\\res\\values\\google-services.xml' } }

aaptOptions {
    noCompress = ['.unity3d', '.ress', '.resource', '.obb', 'google-services.json']
    ignoreAssetsPattern = "!.svn:!.git:!.ds_store:!*.scc:.*:!CVS:!thumbs.db:!picasa.ini:!*~"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in my case i have setted prograurd mode in release setting under publish settings>minify>release . Setting this to none have fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

That particular issue is related to the google-services.json file that *should* be automatically included in your build if the file exists in your Assets/ directory. Note that the process is different enough from the Android process that you probably need to ignore the Firebase Android instructions and only follow the [Unity ones](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup) unless you [really know what you're doing](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin).

I'll tackle the easiest problem first. Make sure you have your `google-services.json` file in your `Assets/` directory. I usually keep mine in `Assets/Data/` (which is where I also keep things like ScriptableObjects). If you don't have it, follow the instructions on the [Download Firebase config file or object help page](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592?hl=en):

> Get config file for your Android app Go to your the Settings icon
> Project settings in the Firebase console. In the Your apps card,
> select the package name of the app for which you need a config file.
> Click  google-services.json. Move your config file into the module
> (app-level) directory of your app. Make sure that you only have this
> most recent downloaded config file in your app.

Once you have that file, you'll need to make sure that `Assets/Plugins/Android/Firebase/res/values/google-services.xml` gets properly generated:

[image: Screenshot showing google-services.xml in the Android Plugins directory]

The reason why this exists is that the Unity SDK does not use the [Google Services Gradle Plugin](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin) - doing so would break compatibility with older versions of Unity or teams that otherwise opt out of gradle integration. This is why I **strongly advise against** following any of the [Android specific documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) unless you're willing to do a lot of work by hand.

If you do not have `google-services.xml` or you want to try to regenerate it, you should navigate to Assets>External Dependency Manager>Android Resolver>Force Resolve:

[image: The resolve menu in Unity]

If this does fix your issue, then you should make sure that you enable auto-resolution to avoid this issue in the future:

[image: Android Resolver Settings window with "Enable Auto-Resolution" and "Enable Resolution On Build" both selected]

There are also a few more subtle issues that crop up. One is that "External Dependency Manager for Unity" is a rename of the "Play Services Resolver" (developers kept thinking that it was tied to Play Services - which it isn't). So check that you don't have a `Assets/Play Services Resolver` directory. Also, if you're using the External Dependency Manager in the Unity Package Manager, make sure that `Assets/External Dependency Manager` doesn't exist as well. Since you're using two plugins that ship with EDM4U, you may have some duplication (although EDM4U should be smart enough to resolve that).

If you're still running into issues, it may help to share your directory layout WRT where the External Dependency Manager, google-services.json, google-services.xml, and the Firebase and the Play Games Sign-In plugin live. Also it could be worth noting if `google-services.xml` makes it into an exported project (or your APK). If any of this isn't something you want to share on Stack Overflow, feel free to reach out to [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support) and link this SO question.

--Patrick

Comment: Thanks for the response, my friend!! The google-services.json is in its right place, and so does the google-services.xml. The External Dependency Manager folder is also there, but it is not in my UPM, so it's alright.
EDM is inside 'Assets\ExternalDependencyManager\Editor', google-services.json: is inside Assets and google-services.xml is inside 'Assets/Plugins/Android/Firebase/res/values' as it should be.
I will try to contact Firebase support - if you have anything else in mind, please let me know. :) Thanks in advance!!!